# For any finite group $G$ of order $n$ show that there exists two subgroups $H_1, H_2 \leq S_n$ isomorphic to $G$ with $h_1h_2 = h_2h_1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

For any finite group $G$ of order $n$ show that there exists two subgroups $H_1, H_2 \leq S_n$ isomorphic to $G$ with $h_1h_2 = h_2h_1$ for all $h_1 \in H_1, h_2 \in H_2$.

Here is my attempt so far:  Let $\sigma, \tau \in S_n$ be defined via cycle notation by $\sigma = (1, 2, ..., n)$ and $\tau = (n, n-1, ..., 1)$.  The order of both $\sigma$ and $\tau$ is $n$, and furthermore $\tau = \sigma^{-1}$.  We can then define

$$
H_1 = \langle \sigma \rangle, \quad H_2 = \langle \tau \rangle
$$

so that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are both cyclic subgroups of $S_n$ of order $n$.  Then we have

$$
H_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong H_2,
$$

and if $h_1 \in H_1, h_2 \in H_2$ then $h_1h_2 = \sigma^i\tau^j = \sigma^i(\sigma^{-1})^j = \sigma^i\sigma^{-j}     \sigma^{i-j} = \sigma^{-j}\sigma^i = \tau^j\sigma^i = h_2h_1$.  This seems to be a solution to the problem, provided that the original group $G$ being considered is cyclic (and therefore isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$).  How do I proceed without the assumption that $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$ however?

Comment: Please put the problem statement in the post itself, not just the title. Is the hypothesis that every element of $H_1$ commutes with every element of $H_2$? What's stopping us from just choosing $H_2=H_1$ (which your example actually does)?

Comment: @Greg: $G$ isn't necessarily abelian. Carl, here's a big hint: consider the action of $G$ on itself by left and then by right multiplication.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, strictly speaking, the right multiplication provides an injective antihomomorphism, so the image is not isomorphic to $G$, but rather to $G^{\operatorname{op}}$.

Comment: $r_a: g\mapsto ga^{-1}$ does the trick.

Comment: @Devo But $G^{\rm op} \cong G$ so it is isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: That's true, as I stated it's not correct, @DerekHolt. Though it requires one more step than directly addressing the "by inverse" right multiplication. I expected some "$r_{ab}=r_br_a$" might have rised a question mark to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: consider the permutations induced by left and right multiplication.

Comment: Letting $G$ act on itself by left multiplication induces a group homomorphism $\varphi: G \rightarrow S_{|G|} = S_n$.  The mapping $\varphi$ is injective, since the kernel of $\varphi$ is the set of all $x \in G$ which satisfy $xg = g$ for all $g \in G$, but this is precisely the set $\{1\}$.  So, since $G$ injects into $S_n$ it follows that $\varphi(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $n$.

Comment: Is this the right direction to take?

Comment: Yes. Now do the same for right action.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming you have at hands that, if $|G|=n$, then $\operatorname{Sym}(G)\cong S_n$.)

Take $H_1:=\{l_a, a\in G\}$ and $H_2:=\{r_a, a\in G\}$, where for every $a\in G$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\operatorname{Sym}(G)\ni l_a\colon g\mapsto ag \\
&\operatorname{Sym}(G)\ni r_a\colon g\mapsto ga^{-1} \\
\end{alignat}
Prove that $l\colon a\mapsto l_a$ and $r\colon a\mapsto r_a$ are injective homomorphisms of $G$ into $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$, whence $H_1,H_2\cong G$. Moreover, given any $a,b\in G$, for every $g\in G$ we get:
\begin{alignat}{1}
(l_ar_b)(g) &= l_a(r_b(g)) \\
&= l_a(gb^{-1}) \\
&= agb^{-1} \\
&= (ag)b^{-1} \\
&= r_b(ag) \\
&= r_b(l_a(g)) \\
&= (r_bl_a)(g) \\
\end{alignat}
and hence $l_ar_b=r_bl_a$ for every $a,b\in G$ (which is yours "$h_1h_2=h_2h_1$ for all *etc.*"). This holds for infinite $G$ either, provided that you replace $S_n$ with $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$. Moreover, it may worth noting that $H_1\cap H_2\cong Z(G)$ and (as a corollary of your claim) $H_1H_2\le\operatorname{Sym}(G)$.

Just to getting familiar with these isomorphic images of $G$ into $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ (we'll come up indeed to a trivial result), in the finite case these two latter facts tell us that: $$|H_1H_2|=\frac{n^2}{|Z(G)|}\mid n! \tag1$$
So, if $G$ is centerless, then from $(1)$ follows $n\mid (n-1)!$, namely $n$ is composite, whence the result that $G$ of prime order can't be centerless (which, as said, is by far trivial being in that case $G$ cyclic, and hence abelian).

A less trivial result with $H_1$ and $H_2$ is the following: an element of $H_1H_2$ (which is a bijection of $G$) is operation-preserving (namely an automorphism of $G$) if and only if, for every $x,y\in G$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&(l_ar_b)(xy)=((l_ar_b)(x))((l_ar_b)(y))&&\iff \\
&axyb^{-1}=axb^{-1}ayb^{-1}&&\iff \\
&e=b^{-1}a&&\iff \\
&b=a&&\iff\\
&l_ar_b=l_ar_a\in\operatorname{Inn}(G)
\end{alignat}
whence: $$\operatorname{Inn}(G)=\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cap H_1H_2$$
thus making somehow plausible calling "inner" the automorphisms by conjugation (after all, isn't $H_1H_2$ "the greater area of $G$" in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$?)